# cordova how to detect if the code is running inside an inappbrowser

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I open a page from my app or from a browser.
When I open the page from the browser, it has the toolbar and statusbar which makes it not so nice.
So 
1. Is there any way to hide them?
2. If I can't hide them, I need to know if the page was invoked from the device browser or from an inappbrowser.

Answer (score -1):

You can differentiate using object returned from window.open

For example, var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

In device browser, ref is a window object and there are no event listeners.

InAppBrowser, ref has event listeners. 
    `ref.addEventListener(eventname, callback);`

Refer for more details https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html#inappbrowserevent

InAppBrowser, you will get `ref.channels` and which is not available in browser

Comment: Do you mean that inside the JS script that runs in the inappbrowser I will open another page and then check the re.channels?
It will look very bad!!!